# AFNetworking see downloaded data

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I'm looking to make some library using AFNetworking (on iOS) to help my future apps to take decisions about the internet connection. Basically I want to have more than 'with internet' or 'without internet'. more like 'no connection, bad connection, not so bad, normal, good, excellent ...'

With that in mind, i started with my library, and using AFNetworking as a client. But I would love to know if is there any way to see how many packages, in size, has the connection downloaded at a certain moment. So with that i could make a 'Downloaded/Time' (speed) expression to grade the speed and or quality of the current connection.

Any ideas where to start looking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in the AFNetworking FAQ:

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-FAQ#how-do-i-track-upload-or-download-progress

This gives you a hook into the download progress; your block gets called periodically with the current byte count. You can use that along with time information to figure out the current rate.

Comment: does that works with regular http request? the idea is that I can get the 'speed' not just downloading something to the phone, but just when getting a response of a http request

Comment: Thanks for the hint! i'm using those methods right now! (i'm kinda new on AFN and iOS also) i'll let you know how the thing goes!